# Cannot find tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, miktex2.9

I am trying to install `tikz` package, but it is not even listed. I am on Win 10 and using MikTex 2.9.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: It is in the MiKTeX package `pgf`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to avoid in future such issues why do you not simply install the complete MiKTeX? Then pgf/Tikz is included ...

Please see that the current version of MiKTeX `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)` has a new MiKTeX Console instead your old shown MiKTeX Package manager. I recommend you update your system, and then use MiKTeX (netinstaller) Complete installer ...

Nevertheless, start MiKTeX Console in admin mode and click on `Packages` (with the old package manager it is nearly the same, you have to start another program with another windows poping up; clicking the + sign installs choosed packages there too):

[image: Console Packages pgf]

Now add `pgf` in the field I marked with red circle 1 and click on the symbol marked with red arrow 2. Then you can see a list of packages containing `pgf` in the name. use Strg-Click to choose the packages you want to install (see the blue marked lines in screenshot above) and click on the + sign marked with red circle 3 (in your case it will be gray/dark, I have already installed that packages, so no need for me to install again).

After installing that packages you will see a new list, now including a date in column `Installed On`.

To install the complete TiKZ you now need to install some packages with name `tikz` in it:

[image: Console tikz packages]

Now do the same we already did for `pgf`. To be sure you get all needed tikz packages simply choose all listed packages (scroll down to see all) and install them via clicking on + sign (red circle 3) ...